# Google Maps Browser Script Not Loading?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, http, general-network-error

I've been having an issue with the google maps script. The request to load the google maps script fails sometimes. In the chrome network tab, it shows an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error while on Firefox, the request status is Aborted. I am loading the script synchronously with the following request:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=myapikey&oe=utf-8&hl=en
```

This error never used to occur but now it seems to come and go randomly, sometimes on Chrome and sometimes on Firefox. One minute the script doesn't load and after a while, it works fine. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: It may be issue of connectivity.Please add it to head

Comment: Thanks Niketan. The other scripts load fine on the page but the issue only seems to happen with the google maps script.  That is the strange thing.

Comment: Based from this [blog](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fix-ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED-on-Chrome), **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** may be fixed by clearing Google Chrome's cache and cookies. A corrupted cookie or cache file may cause this error to show up. Also, many malware applications run in the background and prevent Chrome or other web browsers from connecting to external web servers. Uninstall them & use Windows Defender to do a quick/full system scan.

Comment: Thanks abielita. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Note that you should load API from maps.googleapis.com domain, not maps.google.com. Look at [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)